# Gerrit OWNERS Plugin - adding groups to OWNERS file

Tags: git, plugins, gerrit

I use the [owners plugin](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-plugins.html#owners) to add a list of developers as reviewers to a change automatically, so one of them have to approve it for the change to be committed.

Now, instead of changing the `OWNERS` file every time I need to add / remove a person to the list can I add a gerrit group to the `OWNERS` YAML file? I tried adding a group but it gets ignored.

This is the content of my `OWNERS` file.

```
inherited: true
owners:
- owners_Build_tools
```

It would be helpful to know if it is supported or if there is something wrong with my YAML file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the reviewers plugin and save yourself the headache.

https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/reviewers/

That plugin is just for automatically adding people to a review - but it doesn't effect who can/cannot +2 a review.

You can use the [label code review -2/+2](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-labels.html#label_Code-Review) permission to add any number of groups to have exclusive rights to +2 a review.

Just make sure you also mark the permission as `exclusive` so that only those groups can +2 a review.

It should look like this:

[image]

Comment: DanGordon, But reviewers just adds the names in the config as reviewers but doesn't require one of them to approve a change if the committer had added other reviewers and they reviewed the change.I need to add a component owner/owners approval required to merge a change.

Comment: So I guess I'm not clear what you want since I haven't used the 'owners' plugin. In your use case - what is an 'owner' - is it a list of people who **can** approve a change, or a list of people that **must** approve a change? And I assume when you say "approve", you mean "+2 code review". And in your case - you want to add a group to this existing group?

Comment: https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/owners -- Here you can add a list of people one of whom must give a CR+2. This works for me as my requirement is I want to have at least one subject expert to say it is OK to take this change in.  I looked at the java code in the plugin recently doesn't seem to support groups.

Comment: Well if you use the Gerrit setting properly, you can assign any group to be able to +2 a review. In my project, anyone in the group "myproject-lead-reviewers" has the ability to +2 a review - and they are the only ones who can. If I want to add a group to this permission - I can. I guess the only thing you can't do is add people specifically. It must be a group. But creating groups is easy.

Comment: That is a good point. Thanks. But when you need fine grained control of different modules/folders. Then the owners plugin is helpful. It is kind of my need.